# properties of object in javascript using this and without this

Tags: javascript

I have a variable definition like this :

```
var obj = function(){
this.prop1 = "prop1";
return this;
}

obj.prop2 = "prop2";
```

I am getting an `undefined` value when trying to access `obj().prop2`.

Also , undefined is returned when trying to return `obj.prop1` but `obj.prop2` return `prop2` value.

1. I want to know the cause of undefined value being returned by `obj().prop2`.
2. Is the property `prop2` not part of the same object when doing `obj.prop2 = "prop2"`;
3. Why `obj.prop1` returns `undefined` value.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting an undefined value when trying to access obj().prop2.

This is because `obj()` returns `this`, which the context you executed the function with. But you are assigning `prop2` to the function object, not the context you are returning.

> undefined is returned when trying to return obj.prop1 but obj.prop2 return prop2 value

In your code, `obj` is a function object, and there is no `prop1` property assigned to it. You are assigning `prop1` to the context you execute the function with, which is a big difference.

You can execute `obj()` with another context if you want, that might make more sense:

```
var obj = function() {
    this.prop1 = 'prop1';
    return this;
}.call({ prop2: 'prop2' });
```

This will result in: `{prop2: "prop2", prop1: "prop1"}`

Comment: How can I add prop2 to the context I am returning from within the function. Is it possible ?

Comment: @user2599052 Just add `this.prop2 = 'prop2';` But I would advice against using `this` if you don’t know what it does, because you might pollute the global namespace. It’s safer to just return an object: `return {prop1: 'prop1', prop2: 'prop2'};`

Answer (score 0):

If you want `this` to work(or `instanceOf` ), you will have to use `new`.  The new key words bounds the `this` to newly created object whose prototype is function prototype

If you want to work with out this you can write code as following

```
 var obj = function(propValue){
   return {
        prop1: propValue
    };
}
var objectCheck = obj('prop1');
console.log(objectCheck .prop1);
objectCheck .prop2 = "prop2";
console.log(objectCheck .prop2);
```

It's simple to understand, the obj function returns an object with property prop1 and then later you add prop2 to that object